# Compile NoBatteryNoProblem

Tags: mojave

Can some one help me to compile NoBatteryNoProblem from this https://github.com/bernardowilson/NoBatteryNoProblem.kext to .kext file? I really don't understand how this command line Xcode compile should work. I am using Mac OS Mojave or Catalina.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which steps have you done, where are you stuck?

Comment: I have downloaded Xcode 11.3 + command line, then when I start makefile it starts the command line and there are many options and here is where I'm lost. If I try to drag and drop whole NoBatteryNoProblem.kext-master folder to Xcode I get warning: Could not open file. (/Volumes/moje 750gb/Downloads/NoBatteryNoProblem.kext-master)

Answer (score 2):

The project README explains that it is compiled and loaded using `make`. While you need Xcode's Command Line Tools, it doesn't contain an xcodeproj so you don't open it with Xcode. The instructions require you to download the CLT package, then use `make`.

1. > Xcode with Command Line Tools is required to compile this module.

   ```
   xcode-select --install
   ```
2. > 1. `make`
   > 2. `make load` to load and disable Turbo Boost (will ask for admin privileges)

   ```
    cd /path/to/NoBatteryNoProblem.kext-master
    make
    make load
   ```

Comment: well i must say thank you very very much, i feel like an *** but you learn every day something new. works like charm, thank you again.